# How to remove empty Excel line after loop exception?

Tags: python, excel

I am short before finishing my script and trying to get my head around this.

I have a script that puts certain information from an array `(data)` into Excel lines via a loop. `data_loaded` is an array with script entries. This looks like this:

```
    from get_comp_data import get_comp_data
    from openpyxl import Workbook
    wb = Workbook()
    ws = wb.active
            for z in range(len(data_loaded)):
                try:
                    data = get_comp_data(data_loaded[z])
                    print z
                    ws['A'+str(z+1)] = data[0]
                    ws['B'+str(z+1)] = data[1]
                    ws['C'+str(z+1)] = data[2]
                    ws['D'+str(z+1)] = data[3]
                    ws['E'+str(z+1)] = data[4]
                    ws['F'+str(z+1)] = data[5]
                    ws['G'+str(z+1)] = data[6]
                    ws['H'+str(z+1)] = data[7]
                    ws['I'+str(z+1)] = data[8]
                    ws['J'+str(z+1)] = data[9]
                    wb.save("test.xlsx")
                except Exception:
                    pass
```

However, sometimes an exception is raised in the case `get_comp_data` gets an error. Every time an exception is raised the Excel line is empty.

How can I delete or prevent these lines from being created?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`z` is counted up regardless of an exception occurring or not so rows are skipped. The code has to be written in a way the row number is only incremented when there was no error and the row actually got filled.

Iterating over the index values of a sequence instead of the items is ”unpythonic” anyway.

```
from string import ascii_uppercase
from get_comp_data import get_comp_data
from openpyxl import Workbook

workbook = Workbook()
worksheet = workbook.active

# ...

row_number = 1
for item in data_loaded:
    try:
        data = get_comp_data(item)
    except Exception:
        pass  # Intentionally ignored.
    else:
        for column_name, item in zip(ascii_uppercase, data):
            worksheet[column_name + str(row_number)] = item
        row_number += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

put your line *data = get_comp_data(data_loaded[z])* into a try/except+continue like this :

```
try:
    data = get_comp_data(data_loaded[z])
except :
    continue
```

Comment: Thank you Anth0kuto. However the lines are still emtpy. I think the problem is that z jumps also in the case of an exception. Is there a way to when z jumps from eg. 5 to 7, that data_loaded[7] is not put into line 7 but line 6?